# CoreData returns empty data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

coreData returns empty data when there should not be any, even if you uninstall the application and reinstall it and make a request to Сore Data, the context.fetch returns the data

get all Data in Сore Data

```
func getMyLoadBook(){
    words.removeAll()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Favorite> = Favorite.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(result)
        if result.isEmpty {
            emptyBookMark()
            return
        } else {
            tableView.isHidden = false
        }

        for data in result as [NSManagedObject] {
            if let _ = data.value(forKey: "word"){
                let initData = Words(word: (data.value(forKey: "word") as? [String]) ?? [""], wordDesc: (data.value(forKey: "wordDesc") as? [String]) ?? nil, translation: (data.value(forKey: "translation") as? [String]) ?? [""], translDesc: (data.value(forKey: "translDesc") as? [String]) ?? nil)
                words.append(initData)
            }
        }

    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

I have these functions, but they are not called when I get data from coreData

// creates a path and checks for the presence of an element

```
static func coreDataResult(data: [[String?]?]?, completion: @escaping (NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>, Favorite?, NSManagedObjectContext) -> ()){

    guard let w = data?.first, let word = w, let t = data?.last, let transl = t else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Favorite", in: context) else { return }
        guard let taskObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context) as? Favorite else { return }

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "word == %@", word)
        let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "translation == %@", transl)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Favorite")
        let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate, predicate2])

        fetchRequest.predicate = andPredicate
        completion(fetchRequest, taskObject, context)

    }

}
```

// remove data from Сore Data

```
static func deleteFromCoreData(data: [[String?]?]?){

    coreDataResult(data: data, completion: { (result, taskObject, context) in

        do {
            let fetchedEntities = try context.fetch(result) as! [Favorite]
            if let entityToDelete = fetchedEntities.first {
                context.delete(entityToDelete)
            }
            do {
                try context.save()
                if let data = getDataFromContext(result:fetchedEntities){
                    Analytics.logEvent("RemovedFavorite", parameters: ["word": data.0, "translation": data.1])
                    YMMYandexMetrica.reportEvent("RemovedFavorite", parameters: ["word": data.0, "translation": data.1], onFailure: nil)

                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } catch { print(error) }

    })

}
```

// add data to Сore Data

```
static func saveWithModelToCoreData(_ words: Words){

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        coreDataResult(data: [words.word, words.translation], completion: { (result, taskObject, context) in
            do {
                let fetchedEntities = try context.fetch(result) as! [Favorite]
                if let _ = fetchedEntities.first?.word {
                    print("the element already have in coreData")
                } else {

                    taskObject?.setValue(words.word, forKey: "word")
                    taskObject?.setValue(words.translation, forKey: "translation")
                    taskObject?.setValue(words.descript, forKey: "wordDesc")
                    taskObject?.setValue(words.translDesc, forKey: "translDesc")

                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })

    }

}
```

that's what result returns

```
[<Favorite: 0x283478500> (entity: Favorite; id: 0x281306ee0 <x-coredata:///Favorite/t722DD7F9-8DD7-4AC4-AA20-02324AB1B08713> ; data: {
translDesc = nil;
translation = nil;
word = nil;
wordDesc = nil;
})
```

[image]

Comment: did you try, replacing  `let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Favorite> = Favorite.fetchRequest()` with `let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest< NSFetchRequestResult> = Favorite.fetchRequest()`?

Comment: Unrelated but you are using too many question marks. `[[String?]?]?` is hilarious.  For example why is the parameter in `saveWithModelToCoreData` optional? When you are going to call this method you **do** want to save something.

Comment: @NSCoder I did so

Comment: @vadian  habit of putting optional

Comment: If I understand you right, you say that if you make a fresh install of your app, and then fetch data from core data, an object is returned to you (in your question: id: 0x281306ee0) although you did not store this object before. This is not possible, because if you deinstall the app, all persistent data are deleted. Just double check that you deleted your app, and if the error remains, out comment everything that stores to core data, and try again.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I noticed that after calling coreDataResult coreData prints empty data. I added gif, `coreDataResult` call in second tabBarItem

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are you using a simple core-data setup, where all read and write are done on the main thread to the viewContext.  This setup is fine for simple application where you don't expect to do a bulk import, or have a huge amount of entities. It should simplify a lot of multithread issues so I am a little confused why you have such a complex setup with callbacks and `DispatchQueue.main.async` when everything should just simply run on the main thread.  (Perhaps you are planing for a future with a more complex setup?).

In any event, one of the consequences of this is that any changes to the `viewContext` will appear in your app for the lifetime of the app, even if you don't call `save`.  This is because there is a single context - so even it is not saved, it has still been changed.

In the method `coreDataResult` you create an empty object, and then in `saveWithModelToCoreData` it is either set with values and the context saved or it is found to already exist and no further action is taken. If `coreDataResult` returned on a background context that would be fine.  The empty object would disappear when the background context. The problem is that you are writing to the `viewContext` so the context does not go away, and the object sticks around.

If the application would quit right then, you wouldn't see it in the next launch.  But if save is called any time after, then the empty object will also be saved.

I would suggest not creating objects unless you already know that you want them.  I would refactor so that there is a single function that checks for duplicate, and then creates and set or does nothing. As it is I don't see the value of the two different methods.

Comment: I took note of your advice, the problem was in `guard let taskObject = NSManagedObject (entity: insertInto: context) as? Favorite else { return }`